# How can I use a wildcard on Xpath

Tags: html, bash, xpath, wildcard

```
    cover: $main//*[has-class("aligncenter wp-image-121146 size-large")]//img
    cover: $main//img[has-class("aligncenter wp-image-121146 size-large")]
```

the string has a static part *aligncenter wp-image-* and a dynamic part "*" what I want to do here is concatenate all the posibles "*"

in bash is somthing like this:

```
"aligncenter wp-image-"*
```

How can I make that in Xpath?

Comment: You need to say which version of XPath. In XPath 2.0 (or 3.0 or 3.1) you can use the `matches()` function with a regular expression. In 1.0 you only have `starts-with()` and `contains()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
'//E[@class="aligncenter" and contains(concat(" ", @class, "wp-image-"), " C ")]'
```

This might be more robust, haven't tried a lot of `and` and it looks like you're expecting the classes to be in that order:

```
'//E[contains(concat(" ", @class, "aligncenter wp-image-"), " C ")]'
```

I haven't tested it though, either way, this should help you:

https://gist.github.com/glenpierce/400d5b569094b902f06789d80757454e

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to give an exact XPath solution to this question as you didn't provide sample XML/HTML, and both of the attempted XPath expressions (if they actually are) are invalid.

To answer the title, you can't use wildcalrd like that in XPath 1.0, which is the most widely implemented version of XPath. But you can use `contains()` or `starts-with()` function. The latter seems more suitable in this particular case. For example, the following XPath returns all `img` elements, anyhwere in the document, where `class` attribute value starts with substring 'aligncenter wp-image-' :

```
//img[starts-with(@class, 'aligncenter wp-image-')]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/7AS04koFE)</kbd>**